# PHP o JS Ocultar la contraseña con ****

Tags: javascript, php

estoy con una duda, estoy intentando ver como ocultar la contraseña de conexión a SQL server, estoy un poco perdido, ya que soy nuevo en programación, sé que piden códigos de muestra, pero no se por donde comenzar, si es posible una sugerencia de como hacerlo seria genial. Aclaro que en el codigo, el * lo puse manual, para no mostrar los datos reales de la BD

```
<?php

$servername="******";
$conexion=array("Database"=>"******",
                "UID"=>"******",
                "PWD"=>"*******",
                "CharacterSet"=>"UTF-8");
$con=sqlsrv_connect($servername,$conexion);
```

?>

Comment: Todas las cosas de configuración o datos sensibles (contradrña de la BD, cadenas de conexión, etc) deben de ir en un archivo `.env` que guardará todas esas variables

Comment: Muchas gracias por los consejos y sugerencias, las tomare en cuenta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mis recomendaciones:

1 - La contraseña JAMAS debe ser vista en el frontend, solo en el backend debes implementarla
2 - Si estas en el backend del lado de php y tu codigo esta bien desarrollado, no sera necesario cifrarala.
3 - Lo ideal es leer la contraseña desde un archivo de configuracion que no sea accesible desde el fontend

Saludos desde Venezuela

Answer (score 0):

Encripta la contraseña al momento de insertarla

cuando tengas una clave  `123456` si la encriptas  en la base  de datos tendas  `e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e`

Entonces por mucho que  quieras copiar la contraseña tendaras que desencriptarla para porder utilizarla.

Puedes ver la funcion `password_hash()`  de `php` [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/570300/php-o-js-ocultar-la-contrase%C3%B1a-con)